# javascript setTimeout function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a variable every one second. For that reason I am using setTimeout. But it does not update the variable. It logs out 0 just once. Here is my code

```
var yes=0;
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(yes);
    yes++;
}, 1000);​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**setInterval**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), to finish the repitition you have to clear the interval using clearInterval(yourInterval);

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zya6x/)**

```
var yes=0;
yourInterval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(yes);
    yes++;
}, 1000);​
```

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout does repeat itself only once, try setInterval so that for every second it increments `yes` with 1

but remember to clear the interval after sometime else you get on to a never ending loop

using `clearInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

setTimeOut method is just called once after a specific timeout which in your case is 1000, try to use setInterval method instead

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo with setTimeout](http://jsbin.com/osacup/1/edit)*

If you really want to stick to setTimeout (I appreciate that ;) )

 than just wrap all into a function and recall it inside it self like:

```
var yes=0;
 
(function loop(){

  setTimeout(function () {
  
    console.log(yes);
    yes++;
    loop();  // loop recall
  
  }, 1000);
  
})();
```

Otherwise go for **[setInterval](http://jsbin.com/osacup/2/edit)**:

```
var yes=0;

function count(){  
    console.log(yes);
    yes++;  
}
  
setInterval(count, 1000);
```